# OutputCache with VaryByCustom not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, outputcache

I'm trying to implement caching in ASP.NET MVC 4 using the OutputCache attribute.

Here is my controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
[OutputCache(Duration = CACHE_DURATION, VaryByCustom = "$LanguageCode;myParam", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
public JsonResult MyAction(string myParam)
{
    // this is called also if should be cached!
}
```

And here is the GetVaryByCustomString in the Global.asax:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
{
    var pars = arg.Split(';');
    if (pars.Length == 0) return string.Empty;

    var res = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    foreach (var s in pars)
    {
        switch (s)
        {
            case "$LanguageCode":
                var culture = CultureManager.GetCurrentCulture();
                res.Append(culture.Name);
                break;
            default:
                var par = context.Request[s];
                if (par != null)
                    res.AppendFormat(par);
                break;
        }
    }
    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, res.ToString());
}
```

This method is always called and returns the right value (e.g. `"it123"`).

If I call the action with the only `myParam` parameter, the cache works correctly.

```
http://localhost:1592/MyController/MyAction?myParam=123 // called multiple times always read from cache
```

The problem is that when I call the action with another parameter, not included in the `VaryByCustom` string, the controller action is called anyway, also if is should be cached and the `GetVaryByCustomString` returns the same result.

```
http://localhost:1592/MyController/MyAction?myParam=123&dummy=asdf // called multiple times with different 'dummy' values always calls the action
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you have to change your `[OutputCache]` to include `VaryByParam=""`:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = CACHE_DURATION, VaryByCustom = "$LanguageCode;myParam", VaryByParam = "", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
```

Becuase by default its value is `"*"` (All).

Then in your `GetVaryByCustomString()` method, try to return your generated string instead of calling the base method:

```
return res.ToString();
```

Here's the source code of the `base.GetVaryByCustomString()` method:

```
public virtual string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom) {

        if (StringUtil.EqualsIgnoreCase(custom, "browser")) {
            return context.Request.Browser.Type;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

As you can see, it doesn't do what you think it does, it only compares the Browser type with the string you provided and if there's no match it returns `null`, not the `string` you provided.

(I suspect the `[OutputCache]` change alone will suffice, but try changing the method as well)

Comment: You're right about the VaryByParam property. I changed my GetVaryByCustomString only for testing purposes, but now it's ok. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This answer was a lifesaver.

Comment: And for a parameterless action, use `[OutputCache(Duration = CACHE_DURATION, VaryByCustom = "$LanguageCode;", VaryByParam = "", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server)]`