# ASP.NET MVC Caching - Logged-in user gets cached

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, caching

I've a ASP.NET MVC application in which I've implemeneted custom caching filter as below code:

```
public class NonAuthenticatedOnlyCacheAttribute : OutputCacheAttribute
{
    public NonAuthenticatedOnlyCacheAttribute()
    {
        Duration = 600;  /*default cache time*/
    }

    private bool _partialView;
    public bool PartialView
    {
        get { return _partialView; }
        set
        {
            _partialView = value;
            if (_partialView)
            {
                VaryByCustom = "user";
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (PartialView) OnCachePartialEnabled(filterContext);
        else OnCacheEnabled(filterContext);

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    private OutputCacheLocation? originalLocation;
    private int? _prevDuration;

    protected void OnCachePartialEnabled(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;

        if (!_prevDuration.HasValue) _prevDuration = Duration;
        Duration = httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? 1 : _prevDuration.Value;
    }

    protected void OnCacheEnabled(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;

        if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // it's crucial not to cache Authenticated content
            originalLocation = originalLocation ?? Location;
            Location = OutputCacheLocation.None;
        }
        else
        {
            Location = originalLocation ?? Location;
        }

        // this smells a little but it works
        httpContext.Response.Cache.AddValidationCallback(IgnoreAuthenticated, null);
    }

    // This method is called each time when cached page is going to be
    // served and ensures that cache is ignored for authenticated users.
    private void IgnoreAuthenticated(HttpContext context, object data, ref HttpValidationStatus validationStatus)
    {
        validationStatus = context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
          ? HttpValidationStatus.IgnoreThisRequest
          : HttpValidationStatus.Valid;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is, even though I'm not caching the page for authenticated user, sometimes I'm seeing a cached page of some other authenticated user. This happens rarely and randomly.

If I debug through this, it works perfectly fine but not when it occurs on LIVE site.
What I'm also seeing is, a cookie (".AspNet.ApplicationCookie") of the authenticated user gets created in browser as well. (Does it mean that output cache is also caching response cookies as well?)
If I delete this cookie then user gets logged out which is obvious.

In Global.asax, I have following code:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string value)
    {
        if (value.Equals("culture") || value.Equals("user"))
        {
            var customString = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
            if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                customString = $"{context.User.Identity.Name}-{customString}";
            }
            return customString;
        }
        return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, value);
    }
```

And on controller, below attribute is cached

```
[NonAuthenticatedOnlyCacheAttribute(Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server, Duration = 600, VaryByCustom = "user")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be that you did not tell ASP.NET what you mean with:

```
VaryByCustom = "user"
```

Maybe you did that, but the code is not included in your post. 
In your Global.asax.cs you will have something like:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg) 
{ 
    if (arg.Equals("User", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) 
    {
        var user = context.User.Identity.Name; // TODO here you have to pick an unique identifier from the current user identity
        return string.Format("{0}@{1}", userIdentifier.Name, userIdentifier.Container); 
    }

    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg); 
}
```

You can find more information on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22995363/6996150) and [here](http://blog.danielcorreia.net/asp-net-mvc-vary-by-current-user/).

Comment: The code in your global.asax.cs to take into account the user seems incorrect. You return "Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name" which is the culture code. I think you need to return something that identifies the user, as in the above code example and as explained in the articles I referred to.

Comment: I'll give it a try and confirm. I think I understood your point though!

Comment: I've implemented code and moved to production. I shall wait for few more days for this problem to reoccur otherwise I'll mark the above one as Correct answer. :)

Comment: Cool. Good luck!

Comment: userIdentifier uses a deprecated package Microsoft.Identitymodel.Clients.ActiveDirectory